# Pandas Dataframe do something in column A based on column B being True or False

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have for example 2 columns in my Dataframe

```
    A    B
0   4   True
1   3   False
2   4   False
3   3   True
```

And I now want to add 1 to the value in A if B is `True` and subtract 2 if B is `False`.

Is there a clean way to put this in an if without looping through all rows? What I really want to do is a bit more complicated than subtracting and adding but I simplified it here for the question. So I am happy about not super short answers specified to adding 1 and subtracting 2.

Hope someone can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` in which you use column "B" as the condition:

```
df['A'] = np.where(df['B'], df['A'].add(1), df['A'].sub(2))
```

Output:

```
   A      B
0  5   True
1  1  False
2  2  False
3  4   True
```

Comment: I appreciate the fast response, but this only does half of what I need plus I dont need it to add 1 in my real code. I just need a way to do something to A if B is True and something else if B is negative. 
I actually check if the time that is stored in A is correct. If B is True the time is fine, if its False I have to add +1 day to it as the day changed from 23:59 to 00:00
Thats what I actually need to do but I figured that it would only complicate things if I tried to explain that.

Comment: @Pasgru it's the same concept, use `df["B"]` as the condition and use `np.where` to assign values to "A". Just replace `df['A'].add(1)` with `"df['A']"`, and `df['A'].sub(2)` with `"add +1 day"`

Comment: And although I have been here for over 5 years I still can't upvote yet because not enough reputation :') but yes accepted your answere

Comment: There we go. You should have enough rep now @Pasgru :)

Comment: FYI: a possibly more readable version of @enke's answer would be `df['A'] = np.where(df['B'], df['A'] + 1, df['A'] - 2)`

Comment: Thanks here the code I used that maybe explains a bit why I rephrased the question:
`df[column] = np.where(df["time_ok"], pd.to_datetime(df["CREATION DATE"] + ' ' + df[column],
                                        format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'), pd.to_datetime(df["CREATION DATE"] + ' ' + df[column],
                                        format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') + datetime.timedelta(days=1))`

Comment: @Pasgru perhaps it's more efficient to write it in two lines: `df[column] = pd.to_datetime(df["CREATION DATE"] + ' ' + df[column], format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S'); df[column] = np.where(df["time_ok"], df[column], df[column] + datetime.timedelta(days=1))`